Why are the Indian Candidates' names spelt the way they are?
(Not sure if this is a chess question, but it is inspired by chess.)
As I write this, the 2024 Candidates tournament is in progress. There are three Indians in contention: R Praggnanandhaa, Vidit Gujrathi, and Gukesh D.
Why is it that their names are spelt this way, instead of in full (Rameshbabu Praggnanandhaa, Dommaraju Gukesh)? For that matter, why is Praggnanandhaa's last name spelt out while the first name is abbreviated, while the opposite is true for Gukesh, and neither is true for Vidit? Furthermore, why do people refer to Vidit as Vidit instead of Gujrathi (c.f. people also use Nepomniachtchi, Caruana, Abasov, etc., and not the first name)?

My suspicion is it's a collision of what name part is easier to pronounce for the general public, the (resulting) oft used shorthand used to uniquely refer to them , and maybe a pinch of personal request.

I remember an interview of Anand explaining he was amused how his patronym Vishwanathan (i.e. his father's name) had been confused for a occidental firstname and became the basis of his nickname "Vishy".

On the official website of the event, https://candidates2024.fide.com/players , Vidit's name is even given in full "Vidit Santosh Gujrathi". It is the only one expanding on two lines, so I don't think a lack of space is the reason why Gukesh' and Pragg's nams have been abbreviated. Maybe the web designer was afraid of mispellings ?

As I understand it, names in India don't all fit into the Anglo-American (not even universal in all of Europe) standard of first (given) name and last (family) name.  Worse yet, even different parts of India have different norms regarding how people have and use their names.  It's not surprising that attempts to shoehorn a naming schema from a foreign culture onto a culture where the schema doesn't fit results in lots of inconsistent awkwardness.

Just a note that most people refer to Hikaru by his first name. Magnus, too.

so you're asking 2 questions 1 - abbreviation 2 - interchanging 1st and last name?

@SteveBennett actually, there are 2 questions here. for the 2nd question, Vidit Gujrathi's 'given name' is Vidit, but the 'family name' listed is 'Vidit' not 'Gujrathi'. It's an Indian name thing. Nothing really to do with chess. In India, some don't have like 'family names' exactly but some kind of 'patronymics' like their last name is the given name of their dad or something. Like if I'm 'John Smith' then my children could be 'Ashanti John', 'Bidatz John', etc.

(Partial answer)
Looks like there's more variation in Indian names than one might think at first glance.
R Praggnanandhaa appears to be a Tamil name. In this kind of name, Praggnanandhaa is the given name, and Rameshbabu is the name of the father. You can see this also from Praggnanandhaa's sister's name, R Vaishali, where the 'R' is also short for Rameshbabu.
Gukesh's name is a Telugu name. The last name is given first, then the given name (this naming style is also the way Chinese, Korean, Japanese and a few other countries' names work). Wiki also says "Unlike western names, where family name often takes prominence over given name, in the Telugu-speaking states, a person is well-known by their given name, often without ever hearing their family name". Hence Gukesh's name is Gukesh, and his last name is not commonly spelt out. This does beg the question of why Gukesh's name is not given as D Gukesh. I don't know, unless it's to do with the Western name ordering of giving the first name before the last name.
Finally Vidit's name appears the easiest to understand for Western audiences, since Goan names are just first name - middle name - last name.

Actually, there are 2 questions here.
For the 1st question, I guess lacking space.
For the 2nd question, This has nothing really to do with chess. It's an Indian name thing.
Vidit Gujrathi's 'given name' is Vidit, but the 'family name' listed is 'Vidit' not 'Gujrathi'.  In India, some don't have like 'family names' exactly but some kind of 'patronymics' like their last name is the given name of their dad or something. Like if I'm 'John Smith' then my children could be 'Ashanti John', 'Bidatz John', etc. See the following for explanation:

https://reddit.com/14j7rk8

https://reddit.com/14oex7n


There's a table there, that I've copied below. Notice how Tania Sachdev is the only anomaly (unless Vishy is an anomaly too. Not sure). Either Wikipedia is wrong or Tania is from a part of India that the others aren't or something.



Player name on Wikipedia
Given name
Last name
Wikipedia refers to them by
Which comes 1st given or last name?




Rameshbabu Vaishali
Vaishali
Rameshbabu
given name
last name


Rameshbabu Praggnanandhaa
Praggnanandhaa
Rameshbabu
given name
last name


Vidit Gujrathi
Vidit
Gujrathi
given name
given name


Viswanathan Anand
Anand
Viswanathan
given name
last name


Koneru Humpy
Humpy
Koneru
given name
last name


Tania Sachdev
Tania (I think?!)
Sachdev (I think?!)
last name
given name


Harika Dronavalli
Harika
Dronavalli
given name
given name


Nihal Sarin
Nihal
Sarin
given name
given name





Telugu names always had surname first and generally just the letter.
Only recently as Telugus migrated out a lot both within India and outside, we have started to put our surname last. So D. Harika is now written as Harika Dronavalli. Praggnanandhaa is also a Telugu living in Tamil Nadu for a couple of generations and has now changed their naming style to include father’s name.

Perhaps theirs a character limit when registering names in FIDE, or it could be personal preference.
